# How to put foreach into separate variables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, joomla

I've searched this forum for 2 days now but I can't seem to get a grip on the "foreach" thing.

I found this:

Which is exactly what I need, but!
How do I get the output "echo "$key = \"$value\"
";" in reusable variables???

```
    <?php
    /* Create Array named $profile with contents of jos_users */
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    foreach ($user as $key => $value)
    {
    $profile[$key] = $value;
    }

    /* Extract jos_user_profiles data and add to $profile */
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('profile_key, profile_value');
    $query->from('#__user_profiles');
    $query->where('user_id = '. (int) $user->id);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
    $profile[$row->profile_key] = $row->profile_value;
    }

    /* Included for debugging purposes only 8*/
    foreach ($profile as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "$key = \"$value\"<br/>";
    }
    ?>
```

the output generated is like:

```
    id = "636"
    name = "test2"
    username = "test2"
    email = "test2@test.nl"
    password = "$P$DcH9yo/xVoU7vTXgvmwCrCn5dDwfnE0"
    password_clear = ""
    block = "0"
    sendEmail = "0"
    registerDate = "2014-04-11 18:49:24"
    lastvisitDate = "2014-04-12 07:51:45"
    activation = ""
    params = "{}"
    groups = "Array"
    guest = "0"
    lastResetTime = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    resetCount = "0"
    _errors = "Array"
    aid = "0"
    otpKey = ""
    otep = ""
    testprofile.phonenumber = "523657543763"
```

What I want is the output into variables, like "id = "636"" becomes $id = "636", or $variablename = "636"

is there a way I can generate/declare automated variables from the above code? (and list them, so I can see which variables were declared).

What I want to do is:

get the data from $user and reuse that to insert/update changed mysql data into an MsSQL database through this code:

```
    include ('includes/connectwk.php');

    $sql = "select DEEL_ID, DEEL_TEAM, DEEL_NAAM, DEEL_TELEFOON, DEEL_MAIL from         WK_DEELNEMERS where DEEL_ID = '$usr_id'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

    if( $stmt === false)
    {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    echo 'connection failed!';
    }

    //script part
    if ($usr_id === 0 or $usr_login === null)
    {}
    else
    {
    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt))
    {
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $c_id   =   $row['DEEL_ID'];
        $c_team =   $row['DEEL_TEAM'];
        $c_naam =   $row['DEEL_NAAM'];
        $c_tel  =   $row['DEEL_TELEFOON'];
        $c_mail =   $row['DEEL_MAIL'];

        if ($usr_id === $c_id and $usr_login === $c_team and $usr_mail === $c_mail and $row['DEEL_NAAM'] === $usr_name)
        {
        $update = false;
        }
        else
        {
        $update = true;
        }
    }
}
else
{
$sql = "insert into WK_DEELNEMERS (DEEL_ID, DEEL_TEAM, DEEL_NAAM, DEEL_TELEFOON, DEEL_MAIL) values ('$usr_id','$usr_login','$usr_name','','$usr_mail')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
echo 'insert uitgevoerd';
}
if ($update === true)
{
    $sql ="update WK_DEELNEMERS set DEEL_TEAM = '$usr_login',DEEL_NAAM = '$usr_name',DEEL_TELEFOON ='bla3',DEEL_MAIL= '$usr_mail' where DEEL_ID = '$usr_id '"; 
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
}

    }
    ?>
```

Probably this is not the way to do it, but as I am learning, please feel free to "push" me in the right direction. :)

In short, what I am trying to accomplish is, get the data from the mssql prefix_user table and the prefix_user_profiles table.

compare those results with the results I got from the MsSQL table and insert/update the MsSQL table if the user updated/changed his profile through the website.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

Ok, when I do this:

```
    <?php
    $profile["id"] = "636";
    $profile["name"] = "test2";
    $profile["username"] = "test2";
    $profile["email"] = "test2@test.nl";
    $profile["password"] = "$P$DcH9yo/xVoU7vTXgvmwCrCn5dDwfnE0";
    $profile["password_clear"] = "";
    $profile["block"] = "0";

    foreach ($profile as $key => $value)
    {
      $$key = $value;
    } 

    echo $id;

    ?>
```

I get: 636 (which I want)

but when I do this:

```
    <?php
    /* Create Array named $profile with contents of jos_users */
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    foreach ($user as $key => $value)
    {
    $$key = $value;
    }

    ?>
```

I get a blank page. and by blank page I mean, I run this php from a Joomla Article and the whole template shows up blank in the browser. not because I'm not using an echo in the 2nd script.

I don't get it :/

@ Hüseyin BABAL here is the var_dump($user);

```
    object(JUser)#35 (26) { ["isRoot":protected]=> bool(false) ["id"]=> string(3) "636" ["name"]=> string(5) "test2" ["username"]=> string(5) "test2" ["email"]=> string(13) "test2@test.nl" ["password"]=> string(34) "$P$DcH9yo/xVoU7vTXgvmwCrCn5dDwfnE0" ["password_clear"]=> string(0) "" ["block"]=> string(1) "0" ["sendEmail"]=> string(1) "0" ["registerDate"]=> string(19) "2014-04-11 18:49:24" ["lastvisitDate"]=> string(19) "2014-04-12 13:38:55" ["activation"]=> string(0) "" ["params"]=> string(2) "{}" ["groups"]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(1) "2" } ["guest"]=> int(0) ["lastResetTime"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["resetCount"]=> string(1) "0" ["_params":protected]=> object(JRegistry)#36 (1) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#37 (0) { } } ["_authGroups":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) } ["_authLevels":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) } ["_authActions":protected]=> NULL ["_errorMsg":protected]=> NULL ["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } ["aid"]=> int(0) ["otpKey"]=> string(0) "" ["otep"]=> string(0) "" }
```

@ Hüseyin BABAL here is the var_export($user); Thanks :)

```
    JUser::__set_state(array( 'isRoot' => false, 'id' => '636', 'name' => 'test2', 'username' => 'test2', 'email' => 'test2@test.nl', 'password' => '$P$DcH9yo/xVoU7vTXgvmwCrCn5dDwfnE0', 'password_clear' => '', 'block' => '0', 'sendEmail' => '0', 'registerDate' => '2014-04-11 18:49:24', 'lastvisitDate' => '2014-04-12 17:27:36', 'activation' => '', 'params' => '{}', 'groups' => array ( 2 => '2', ), 'guest' => 0, 'lastResetTime' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'resetCount' => '0', '_params' => JRegistry::__set_state(array( 'data' => stdClass::__set_state(array( )), )), '_authGroups' => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, ), '_authLevels' => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, ), '_authActions' => NULL, '_errorMsg' => NULL, '_errors' => array ( ), 'aid' => 0, 'otpKey' => '', 'otep' => '', ))
```

@ Hüseyin BABAL and here is the output for var_dump(get_object_vars($user));

```
    array(20) { ["id"]=> string(3) "636" ["name"]=> string(5) "test2" ["username"]=> string(5) "test2" ["email"]=> string(13) "test2@test.nlDit e-mailadres wordt beveiligd tegen spambots. JavaScript dient ingeschakeld te zijn om het te bekijken. " ["password"]=> string(34) "$P$DcH9yo/xVoU7vTXgvmwCrCn5dDwfnE0" ["password_clear"]=> string(0) "" ["block"]=> string(1) "0" ["sendEmail"]=> string(1) "0" ["registerDate"]=> string(19) "2014-04-11 18:49:24" ["lastvisitDate"]=> string(19) "2014-04-12 17:50:44" ["activation"]=> string(0) "" ["params"]=> string(2) "{}" ["groups"]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(1) "2" } ["guest"]=> int(0) ["lastResetTime"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["resetCount"]=> string(1) "0" ["_errors"]=> array(0) { } ["aid"]=> int(0) ["otpKey"]=> string(0) "" ["otep"]=> string(0) "" }
```

thing I have to mention is that with this script:

```
    <?php
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $userArr = (array) $user;
    foreach($userArr as $key => $value) 
    {
    $$key = "$value";
    }
    echo $id;
    ?>
```

it throws a: 500 internal server error?

I got this popup message after I just installed the full_ajax plugin for Joomla.

ok, now I tried this (hope I did it correctly)

```
    <?php
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $userArr = get_object_vars($user);
    foreach($userArr as $key => $value)
    {
    $$key = $value;
    }
    echo $id;
    ?>
```

still 500 internal server error. doesn't matter if I take the echo out or not.

Comment: You can use vaiable variables to do that, you can see my answer and demo.

Comment: Could you please check error logs? If there is 500 error, there must be error definiton in error log

Comment: Sorry it's taking so long, i'm trying to find the log files Joomla should write. Also trying to find server logs on the server itself.
it throws this: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\www\xampp\htdocs\super11clean\plugins\content\pagenavigation\pagenavigation.php on line 44

Comment: ok, that is the plugin trying to display the article: row 44 says:
  if (($context == 'com_content.article') && ($view == 'article') && $params->get('show_item_navigation'))

Comment: Could you please try with disabling that plugin

Comment: Sorry, can't disable that plugin. it's standard Joomla functionality. Can't even find it in the plugin_manager. I don't think we should tinker with the Joomla installation files..lol

Comment: I think this might be the problem??

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\www\xampp\htdocs\super11clean\plugins\content\DirectPHP\DirectPHP.php(58) : eval()'d code on line 1

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\www\xampp\htdocs\super11clean\plugins\content\DirectPHP\DirectPHP.php(58) : eval()'d code on line 8

Looks like directphp doesn't "know" how to handle $$...etc and make variables from an array??.

Comment: However, PHP knows how to handle variable variables. There is nother problem there. By the way, Above errors are before my code right?

Comment: Hi Hüseyin, thanks again for all the help, I placed a "solution" as an answer to my own question that works for me and gives me all the variables I need for my script. Take a look if you have time. thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the complete approach and created this: (works for me, probably not the best solution, but like I said, it works and i'm still learning PHP)

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $session = JFactory::getSession(); //get cuurent session
    $session->set('user', new JUser($user->id)); //update changed profile settings
    //new data for your user after the update
    $user = JFactory::getUser();

    $usr_id     = $user->get('id');
    $usr_login  = $user->get('username');
    $usr_name   = $user->get('name');
    $usr_mail   = $user->get('email');
    $guest      = $user->guest;

    /*
    echo $guest;
    echo $usr_id;
    echo $usr_login;
    echo $usr_name;
    echo $usr_mail;
    */

// init Joomla Framework
    if ($guest === 0)
    {
        define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');

        // DBQuery
        $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT profile_value FROM #__user_profiles WHERE user_id = '$user->id' AND profile_key LIKE 'testprofile.%'";
        $database->setQuery($query);
        $telnr = $database->loadResult();

       print_r($telnr);


    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'my id is '.$usr_id.' and username is '.$usr_login.' and phonenumber '.$telnr;
```

?>

This gives me the results as I need them.

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**variable variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like;

```
......    
foreach ($profile as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$$key = \"$value\";\n";
}
```

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://ideone.com/sziGnI)**

**Edit:** You are trying to iterate object. You can use `get_object_vars` to get object properties;

```
$userArr = get_object_vars($user);
foreach($userArr as $key => $value) {....
```

Comment: first of all, Thanks for the quick replies!! I love the demo, thanks :)

so the echo "$$key = \"$value\";\n"; does the trick?? gawd, I've spent almost 2 days on this. Maybe I should get a new hobby :(

let me get this straight, the extra $ is for creating the variable, the \n I don't get yet, but i'll google that. Point is, I have to understand what it does. :) thanks again!

Comment: `\n` is new line character. You have used `<br>` it is for just html new line, won't work in code part. It will be printed as text. I have used `\n` for new line to make variable assignments visible pretty. As you can see in demo, variable assignments have declared in separate lines. If I wouldn't use that, Variable assignments will be appended each other, and you would see declaration in one line. And for variable variables, `$$key` does the trick. It hink you have no need further explanation for `$$key` part?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :) greatly appreciated :)

but, when I do this:

          /* Included for debugging purposes only 8*/
          foreach ($profile as $key => $value)
          {
          echo "$$key = \"$value\";\n";
          }

          echo "$id";
          ?>

the $id returns no value, and that is what I'm trying to do. reuse the created $id (which should contain a value 636) in the rest of my scrit. I'm sure i'm missing something, but I can't seem to get what :/

Comment: arent those variables stored in memory?
what I normally use is: $usr_id = $user->get('id');
That way the declared $usr_id is stored in memory and I can reuse that variable through the rest of my script. that's what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: In demo, I just echoed it. If you can use `$$key = $value;`, this will declared in real. And you can use that variable in next lines of your code

Comment: Joomla doesn't like when I change the line: echo "$$key = \"$value\";\n"; into: $$key = $value; the whole page explodes :/ it just shows a totally blank page in the browser, meaning the whole template.
I'm using the directphp plugin for Joomla, maybe it doesn't like me tinkering...lol

Comment: I think, there is something wrong with the script itself, I used your example to test if the $$key would actually work. it does, it gives me a value when I say: echo $id; however, when I use the code I placed above, it crashes when I replace the "echo"$$key..." into SSkey. very weird. It echo's perfectly when I use the echo command.

Comment: I turned on error logging within Joomla, it doesn't display any error messages when I run the script.

Comment: Hi Hüseyin, when you have time, would you be so kind to take another look at my edited post? thanks :)

Comment: @Treborov I have looked at updated question and could you please tell me the output of `var_dump($user);` in your problematic code after `$user =& JFactory::getUser();`?

Comment: Can't put the output in here, it's too long :(
I'll put it in the original post.

Comment: Sorry it is not `var_dump` you will use `var_export($user)`. Could you please also provide that in your question?

Comment: Your `user` object is not an array. Cast it to array and then try. You can see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, tried that and used the $$key =$value; option. Same thing, blank page in browser. when i do: echo "$$key = '$value'"; it shows all the output. I'm about to give up and put this Jquery in the bin :/

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(get_object_vars($user));` ?

Comment: @Treborov You can use `$userArr = get_object_vars($user);` See my updated answer

Comment: I added the output, also I installed full ajax support for Joomla and it throws a 500 server error when I use the $$key option. I posted all the info in the original edit. thanks again for looking at this weird problem. all I need is variables, why does this have to be so hard? I thought they said Joomla, PHP and Jquery was easy.... I say..it isn't...lol

Comment: @Treborov Could you please try `$userArr = get_object_vars($user);` and iterate? see my updated answer

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Iterate? I know what an iteration is, but I don't understand what you want me to do..sorry :( I tried the script and.. wait, I'll post it in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

PHP boasts a useful [array function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) called [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to do exactly what you want. It pulls the elements of an array into the current symbol table (itself an array under the covers).

```
...   
foreach ($resultset as $row)  {
    extract( $row, EXTR_OVERWRITE, 'row_');

    /*now your row elements are in the symbol table with names starting with row_ */

    echo "id = $row_id";
    echo "name = $row_name";
}
```